# Java thread hung in a native method

Tags: java, jvm, threadpool, freeze, thread-dump

While parsing a date string the thread hung in the native method. The thread is stopped in the same state for the last 18 hours(Thread dumb in different times shows the same show the same stack for the thread in question).

Please suggest what might be the error

```
"DateParsingThread - 001" #228 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f98e0029000 nid=0x9c2 runnable [0x00007f98016ee000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.util.resources.LocaleData.getBundle(LocaleData.java:163)
    at sun.util.resources.LocaleData.getDateFormatData(LocaleData.java:127)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleResources.getCalendarNames(LocaleResources.java:325)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.CalendarNameProviderImpl.getDisplayNamesImpl(CalendarNameProviderImpl.java:157)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.CalendarNameProviderImpl.getDisplayNames(CalendarNameProviderImpl.java:139)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.CalendarDataUtility$CalendarFieldValueNamesMapGetter.getObject(CalendarDataUtility.java:178)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.CalendarDataUtility$CalendarFieldValueNamesMapGetter.getObject(CalendarDataUtility.java:154)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleServiceProviderPool.getLocalizedObjectImpl(LocaleServiceProviderPool.java:281)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleServiceProviderPool.getLocalizedObject(LocaleServiceProviderPool.java:265)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.CalendarDataUtility.retrieveFieldValueNames(CalendarDataUtility.java:88)
    at java.util.Calendar.getDisplayNames(Calendar.java:2178)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.getDisplayNamesMap(SimpleDateFormat.java:2366)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.subParse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1972)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:364)
```

Any suggestions to find the solutions are welcome.

Comment: Probably your bundle is blocking the thread (you could debug the `java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl` method and watch what resource is blocking de process).

Comment: This might me a JVM-level deadlock. Try `jstack -m` to get the native part of the stack.

Comment: thanks @apangin will check

Comment: Where is the "native method" part? (how did you find out that it's blocked in a native method?)

Comment: at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

from this @JurajMartinka